# Conditional Probability (2 Urns)

Tags: probability

A gold urn contains 3 red and 4 white balls and a silver urn contains 5 red and white balls. A die is rolled and, if a six shows, one ball is selected at random from the gold urn. Otherwise a ball is selected at random from the silver urn. Find the probability of selecting a red ball. The ball selected is not replaced and a second ball is selected at random from the same urn. Find the probability that both balls are white.

Comment: How many white balls in the silver urn?

Comment: @scott Oh, it's 2.

Comment: @Bram28 I'm quite bamboozled, though I've tried letting A=event where six is the outcome of the roll, B=event where a red ball is gotten in the gold urn, C=event where a red ball is gotten in the silver urn but now I'm stuck with putting everything together.

Comment: OK, that's a good start!  OK, the chance of getting a red ball equals the chance of getting a red ball from the silver urn + the chance of getting a red ball from the gold urn, i.e. P(B)+P(C). (this is all talking about the first ball you pick, by the way). Do you see that?

Comment: if you roll a 6 - what is the probability that you then get a red ball? Then what is the prob of getting a 6 AND a red ball - that is half of it - you can also separately get not6 then a red ball

Comment: another technique is drawing a probability tree - your first 2 branches are 6 and not 6, then coming from those red and white ball (total of 4 possibilities)

Comment: @Bram28 So I reworked my representation, letting A=6 is outcome of the roll, B=event that a red ball is gotten then using the Theorem of Total Probabilities, I plugged in values in the formula P(A)=P(A|B)*P(B) + P(A|B complement)*P(B complement) getting 0.6667. Now the only thing that I don't get is the probability that both balls are white.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton I'd like to know your thoughts on my proposed solution too

Comment: @Azrael  If A=6 with die, then P(A) is simply 1/6 ... no formula needed. Also, I see that you changed your B: now it means just getting red ball, no matter what urn?  Anyway, let's stick with B=red ball from gold urn on first try, and C=red ball from silver urn on first try.  Again, this means that the chance of getting a erd ball on the first try = P(B) + P(C). Do you see this?  It's like saying: what is the chance of getting a 1 or a 2 when rolling a die?  This is: P(1) + P(2) = 1/6+1/6=1/3.  So: when you want the probability of some event that can happen in two ways, add up the probabilitis

Comment: @Bram28 Oh, my bad. It's actually P(B) in the formula, not P(A) since P(A) is already 1/6. But anyhow, got it.

Comment: And by the way, your answer of 2/3 is correct ... so you used the right formula, but the wrong letters ... I still want you to see what exactly is going on here before moving on to the two white balls. So, P(red ball) = P(red ball from gold) + P(red ball from silver) = P(B) + P(C) = ...  [you fill in the rest, using P(A) : die rolls a 6]

Comment: OK, so you did: P(red ball) = P(B or C) = P(B) + P(C) = P(A)*P(red|A) + P(not A)*P(red|not A) = 1/6*3/7 + 5/6*5/7 = 28/42=2/3. Right? Good!

Comment: i concur on 2/3 - now for two white balls, can you compute the probabilites for the 4 different routes at arriving at this - very important - on the second draw the number of balls in the urns has changed

Comment: OK, for the two white balls: P(2 white balls) = P(1st ball white *and* second ball white) = P(1st ball white) * P(2nd ball white|1st ball white).  Now, P(1st ball white) should be easy to figure out. [How?]  and to figure out P(2nd ball white|1st ball white), you can do: P(2nd ball white|1st ball white) = P(2nd ball white|1st ball white from gold urn) + P(2nd ball white|1st ball white from silver urn)

Comment: Yes, Andrew's method may be a little easier to understand. So: P(2 white balls) = P(both white balls from gold run) + P(both whtie balls from silver) + P(1st white ball from gold and 2nd white from silver) + P(1st white from silver and 2nd whitefrom gold) = ...?

Comment: @Azrael  Once you think you have it all, it might actually be a good idea to provide an Answer to your own question. That provides us with a good opportunity that check that you think, phrase, and calculate everything correctly and logically, and it will also be a good opportunity to learn how to create mathematical formulas in this setting.